# Computing a sequence of events over time and extract a percentage of duration

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset which stores events regarding the availability status of a room.

For example, if someone is entering the room at 8:30 am, I get the following row in my table :

```
 #   room  status    date 
---  ----  --------  ------------------- 
 0   A1    OCCUPIED  2022-01-01 08:30:00
```

A similar event is created when this person is leaving the room. My table would then look like this :

```
 #   room  status     date 
---  ----  ---------  ------------------- 
 0   A1    OCCUPIED   2022-01-01 08:30:00
 1   A1    AVAILABLE  2022-01-01 09:15:00
```

In practice, the table has way more entries, and data are intertwined.

```
 #   room  status     date 
---  ----  ---------  ------------------- 
 0   A1    OCCUPIED   2022-01-01 08:30:00 <--
 1   B4    OCCUPIED   2022-01-01 08:32:00
 2   C2    OCCUPIED   2022-01-01 08:41:00
 3   A1    AVAILABLE  2022-01-01 09:15:00 <--
 4   C2    AVAILABLE  2022-01-01 09:20:00
 5   A1    OCCUPIED   2022-01-01 09:30:00 <--
 6   B4    AVAILABLE  2022-01-01 10:00:00
 7   A1    AVAILABLE  2022-01-01 12:00:00 <--
```

I am currently looking for a way to extract a percentage/duration of availability from each of my rooms, but I don't know how to proceed.

I have created a few measures :

```js
// A measure to count the total of status
Count status = COUNT(myTable[status])

// A calculated measure for available ones
Total available = CALCULATE([count status], myTable[status]=="AVAILABLE")
// A calculated measure for occupied ones
Total occupied = CALCULATE([count status], myTable[status]=="OCCUPIED")
```

I already have a date hierarchy which means I can change the granularity from year to month, to week day, to hour of the day. I can also apply a filter to select a range of hours, for example 8:00 to 18:00.

The problem is, the measures I have created simply count the number of changes that occur in a given period (in the chart below, the hours), but they don't reflect the actual duration of each event, which means that my graph is actually wrong.

[image: Current chart]

If I take my room A1 as an example, in the actual configuration, my graph would look like this :

```
            ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
           | 0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |      
available  |   | 50|   |   |100|   |   |   |         
           |   |___|   |   |   |   |   |   |     
           |100|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
occupied   |   | 50|   |   | 0 |   |   |   |
           |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
             8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
```

- In the column 8, 100% occupied because 1 entry in the dataset for this status vs 0 entry for "available".
- In the column 9, 50-50 because 1 entry for each status (one at 09:15, the other at 09:30)
- ...

The result I am looking for is this one :

```
            ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
           |   | 25| 0 | 0 |   |   |   |   |      
available  | 50|___|   |   |100|100|100|100|         
           |___|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |     
           |   | 75|100|100|   |   |   |   |
occupied   | 50|   |   |   | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
           |___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
             8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
```

- In the column 8, I would get 50-50 because the room was available between 08:00 and 08:30, but then it was occupied
- In the column 9, I would get 75% occupied because the room was only available between 09:15 and 09:30
- In the column 10, I would get 100% occupied
- ...

Is it possible to get it through a DAX measure or do I need to restructure some of my data ?

Comment: Perhaps you could increase the number of rows slightly in your example dataset and include your expected result for that dataset?

Comment: @JosWoolley You are right, I added more data

Comment: Many thanks for the expanded dataset. However, you still haven't mentioned any expected results for that data, so it's hard to be sure of what to aim for. Why not clarify what the "percentage/duration of availability from each of my rooms" for the small dataset you posted is?

Comment: @JosWoolley Thanks for the tip, I tried to answer it the best I could in the last two paragraphs of my question

Comment: have you tried sorting by room and date time then using shift to find the previous row date time then calculated the elapsed seconds?  you can then find the total time for the room using min and max and calculate a percentage of occupancy.

Comment: @JrmDel Thanks again. Not to detract from the detailed explanations you've added to your post, but sometimes there's simply no substitute for a few example datasets together with expected results. Your current examples are a touch vague, I'm afraid. For example, your final table suggests that the result for A1 (as derived from your third table, I imagine?) would be 00:45:00, but that third table contains a further entry for A1 which goes unmentioned. Also, as per that example, it's not clear what the result should be in such a case, i.e. in which the last result for a given room is OCCUPIED.

Comment: @JosWoolley I completely changed the last part of my question according to your suggestion. I hope I made it more explicit. Don't hesitate to tell me if you think it's not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to add calculated column to your source table which has the time of next Event in the same room. The Room_No here is your category column.

First, add index by category (by Room)

```
Event_asc = 
VAR Current_Category = Table[Category]
RETURN
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        Table,
        Table[Category] = Current_Category 
    ),
    Table[DateTime], , ASC, Dense
)
```

Then add this column:

```
Event_Next_Time =
VAR Current_Category = Table[Category]
VAR CurIndex = Table[Event_asc]
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table[DateTime] ),
        Table[Category] = Current_Category 
            && Table[Event_asc] = CurIndex + 1,
        REMOVEFILTERS()
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Once you have it, just add a third column which calculates the difference between two Datetimes (Event and NextEvent).

```
Lapse = DATEDIFF( Table[DateTime], Table[TimeOfNextEvent], SECOND )
```

The rest should be easy for you :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That works amazingly well !
I figured there could have been a way to do it only with measures (without calculated columns) but never mind, your way is awesome

Comment: I have one question though, when my events last longer than one hour, they are not displayed throughout my chart when I filter it by hours. Does it come from my hierarchy ? (I added a capture in my original post)

Comment: I can't give answer from the top of my head. I can advice you to create reprex. While solving problems do not work on your production environment. Prepare just a few rows example with only 2 or 3 relevant columns. Chances are that you find the answer right then. If not, paste it as a separate question please.